# How to type-cast a dynamic list to a multi-dimensional typed list in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, casting

If, I have `List<dynamic> dynamicList` which is actually `List<List<double>>` but if I try to cast it using,

```
dynamicList.cast<List<List<double>>>();
```

This gives "not a sub-type error",

Therefore to convert it to `List<List<double>>` I have to,

```
  List<List<double>> converted = [];
  for(int i = 0; i < dynamicList.shape[0]; i++){
    List<double> subList = [];
    for(int j = 0; j < dynamicList.shape[1]; j++){
      if(dynamicList[i][j] is double){
        subList.add((dynamicList[i][j] as double));
      }
    }
    converted.add(subList);
  }
```

```
extension Util on List{
List<int> get shape {
    if (isEmpty) {
      return [];
    }
    var list = this as dynamic;
    var shape = <int>[];
    while (list is List) {
      shape.add((list as List).length);
      list = list.elementAt(0);
    }
    return shape;
  }
}
```

**What could be a better and more generalized way of doing this?**

Comment: You say you tried `dynamicList.cast<List<List<double>>>();`, but `List.cast<R>` returns a `List<R>`, not `R`.  That attempt should be `dynamicList.cast<List<double>>();`.

Answer (score 0):

How to cast a List inside a List
which is a dynamic list

```
List<List<String>> typedList;
typedList = dynamicList.map((value)=>List.cast(value));
```